# Save a region of an image without cropping

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a complex photoshop image with many layers (its for a game). I often want to save a particular rectangle (or two) within the image as png files. Often I will do this many times with different layers being hidden/shown - but always the same rectangle. Currently I am cropping the rectangle, then saving, then re-loading my original (larger image). Is there a way I could save the rectangle without cropping first. Even better if the rectangle region could be remembered between sessions.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly? Can you just use snippingtool or something like that? Do a screencapture using the 'PrtScn' button on your keyboard and then ctrl+v into ms paint and then crop that instead? Or do you need the layers? When you say layers, are you talking about Photoshop layers? Josh

Comment: Can you [show/upload](http://ge.tt/) an example? I'm not sure too if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [slice tool](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7570a.html). It allows you to set regions within your document, and when you save for web, it saves each region separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can select or use a mask, and just Copy, instead of cropping, then paste to the image you want to save. To do what I think you are suggesting, you would want to create a clipping mask and then "copy merged" to make all those visible layers a single image when you paste.